# SharePoint Provider Hosted App Quits with Invalid JWT token

Tags: jwt, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

we have a Provder Hosted app in SharePoint Online running. This has been running almost for one year (or two) without any problems.

But today we got a problem that the Provider Hosted app cannot create a SharePoint Context. After a SAML check we figured out that the secret value was outdated.

So then we added a new set of keys with a new secret described in this post:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726681(v=office.15).aspx
(I also configured the web.config and have the correct TokenHelper.cs)

But for now I gut the following error:

Invalid JWT token. Could not resolve issuer token.

My JWT Token got the following header:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "MnC_VZcATfM5pOYiJHMba9goEKY"
}
```

and this payload:

```
{
  "aud": "aefb17f0-e9d0-455e-ad3b-beb5ed917229/myapp.azurewebsites.net@38de6aa7-8463-4f48-a281-f6492da7fc88",
  "iss": "00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@38de6aa7-8463-4f48-a281-f6492da7fc88",
  "nbf": 1446809939,
  "exp": 1446853139,
  "appctxsender": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@38de6aa7-8463-4f48-a281-f6492da7fc88",
  "appctx": "{\"CacheKey\":\"RSS44EdBaPB95yqMHVTPG6IjJmW9gTCXqB4cEBi5CPk=\",\"NextCacheKey\":null,\"SecurityTokenServiceUri\":\"https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/tokens/OAuth/2\"}",
  "refreshtoken": "IAAAANkH_KL_8o5Ywirb8vICkixTM8ua3nUZhCqpyogpttXy3ovx7HUpgv7pvN8Uy-uVa53kc8gPy2onhFZZTD-6Tc9QcxNxnzSEW3LJdQ8Xdz2KwfMchFq0D0053qtjGQaJY6kt1DR6EcU2fnjrlpBWc2Zxy661GVFFHw4duK0SUNiFMo3OHvHcraXAsLMkWA_LBB9nR5z-u9GieKpBLB9GKiHxyxxuO1ByYgWJoHYCDFffwlsC-AH3TteywkFCBw70FUDw9FyWOVwOHKmUyxmsrGI8HZGuC-J7qa5LGl7villsW-AY-U_uZS-h0zB7iYQI2OVxJt6-KmMDbQkIJHR8XvI",
  "isbrowserhostedapp": "true"
}
```

In some forums I read that I must wait 12 hours so that the new generated secret will be applied. Is that true or did I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. The secret expired, and I followed the steps in the article you linked to generate a new secret. That secret did not work. I gave it 8 hours as I read that it can take a while to work, but no luck.

I then updated the secret using the Seller Dashboard [as per this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220036.aspx), and this worked, but only after a few hours.

Strangely though, on the seller dashboard I don't see the secret I generated using PowerShell, and if I enumerate the secrets in PowerShell I don't see the secret generated on the seller dashboard. All using the same Client Id.